# How to set cookie in PHP cURL request

Tags: php, authentication, curl, cookies, session-cookies

I'm trying to establish a connection with a real-estate listings API in Canada (CREA), and according to the [documentation](http://crea.ca/sites/default/files/Data%20Distribution%20Facility%20Data%20Feed%20Technical%20Documentation_0.pdf):

> A successful Login response header includes a Set-Cookie with
>   X-SESSIONID value. This X-SessionID value needs to be submitted with
>   every request after logging in.

The service provides a sample API for setting everything up, but whenever I attempt to grab the X-SESSIONID value and set it for a subsequent request, it doesn't seem to work, and I get a 401 Unauthorized header on all subsequent requests (even though I am able to successfully grab the X-SessionID info).

Here is the code that I am using now:

```
<?php

  $ch = curl_init('http://sample.data.crea.ca/Login.svc/Login');

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_DIGEST);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'CXLHfDVrziCfvwgCuL8nUahC:mFqMsCSPdnb5WO1gpEEtDCHH');

  $xml = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);

  echo '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars($xml) . '</pre>';

  preg_match('|Set-Cookie: (X-SESSIONID=.*?);.*|', $xml, $match);

  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($match);
  echo '</pre>';

  $ch = curl_init('http://sample.data.crea.ca/Metadata.svc/GetMetadata?Type=METADATA-RESOURCE&Format=STANDARD-XML&ID=0');

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $match[1]);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

  $xml = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);

  echo '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars($xml) . '</pre>';
```

Because this is a sample API available to anyone for free, you can run the code above as is to see the error I am getting.

Any advice on how to properly submit the X-SessionID value so that I can be properly authenticated and make subsequent requests would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '');
```

Now curl will take care of the cookies. You don't need to parse anything or set them manually

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I think you're right in that I have to use `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR`, but I tried putting that line of code in various places, and it doesn't work. Do I also need to use `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE`? What about `CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION`? Also, why the empty string for the third argument? Thanks.